# Why in vuejs app prefer-const rule in vuejs app is not disabled?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

In  @vue/cli app I got error eslint error :

```
  117:11  error  'resArray' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead     prefer-const
  
  pointing at line :
      let resArray = []
```

I disabled this error with adding rule prefer-const = 0 in package.json :

```
{
  "name": "yt3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0-0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "mitt": "^2.1.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.4",
    "vee-validate": "^3.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "semi": [
        2,
        "never"
      ],
      "promise/param-names": [
        0
      ],
      "dot-notation": [
        0
      ],
      "no-trailing-spaces": [
        0
      ],
      "prefer-const": [
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and run command :

```
yarn run serve
```

I expected that last condition with 0 value will disable this erorr, but failed.
Which is valid syntax?

I have file : .eslintrc.js with lines :

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    '@vue/standard'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off'
  }
}
```

Have I to edit it? How it works ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any separate config file (usually `.eslintrc.js`) on the root directory of the app somewhere? Because if you do, that's gonna [take precedence over the `package.json` one](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats).

Comment: I added .eslintrc.js content. Please look

Comment: So you do have one, then you just need to move every rules on `package.json` onto the `.eslintrc.js` file and you should be good to go.

Comment: try `"prefer-const": false`, restart your server, it should disable warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a `.eslintrc.js` file I would suggest moving all your eslint config into there to prevent any conflicts with the `package.json` file.

You should be able to add `'prefer-const': 'off'` to your `rules` to disable that error.

Although if you are only using `resArray` with array operations e.g. `.push()`, `.pop()`, `.splice()` etc and are not going to reassign the value e.g `resArray = []` then you can use `const resArray = []` instead without needing to remove the `prefer-const` rule.

Comment: Thanks!
Have I better to remove all   "eslintConfig": { block from package.json
not to be confused with .eslintrc.js file ?

Comment: @mstdmstd Yes, if you have moved all your eslint config and rules to `.eslintrc.js` then you should remove the `"eslintConfig"` block from `package.json`.